# Why doesn't this formula work? It keeps coming up with formula parse error

Tags: math, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, calculation

I'm trying to create a body fat% calculator (cells B19/C19) that will measure in both metric and imperial (cell B9) depending whether cell B10 is male or female.

I've got the imperial calculation to work just fine, but the metric keeps coming up with **'formula parse error'** - not only that, but even when I separate the male/female calculations for the metric, the male is correct but the female isn't. It's way off what my scientific calculator tells me for the same equation (-68 instead of 32)

I also want to make it so BF% (B19) is dependent on the metrics(B9) instead of having two results. I think a dependent dropdown will be needed here which is fine, but I first need to understand why the formula doesn't work?

Here is the link to my spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14KNBTghqpt4BF6FAgdqNQKEp634E3h3JdScgKISZ4XE/edit?usp=sharing

Height = B11

Neck = B12

Navel = B13

Hip = B14

Here are the raw equations for BF%:

**Body fat % formula for males:**

Imperial Units:

```
BF% = 86.010×log10(navel-neck) - 70.041×log10(height) + 36.76
```

Metric Units:

```
BF% = 495/1.0324 - 0.19077×log10(navel-neck) ) + 0.15456×log10(height)-450
```

**Body fat % formula for females:**

Imperial Units:

```
BF% = 163.205×log10(navel+hip-neck) - 97.684×(log10(height)) - 78.387
```

Metric Units:

```
BF% = 495/1.29579 - 0.35004×log10(waist+hip-neck) + 0.22100×log10(height)-450
```

To clarify, I currently have the formulas set up as such:

**Imperial**

```
=IF(B10="Male",86.01*LOG10(B13-B12)-70.041*LOG10(B11)+36.76,163.205*LOG10(B13+B14-B12)-97.684*LOG10(B11)-78.387)
```

**Metric**

```
=IF(B10="Male",495/1.0324-0.19077*log10(B13-B12))+0.15456*LOG10(B11)-450,495/1.29579-0.35004*LOG10(B13+B14-B12)+0.22100*LOG10(B11)-450
```

Comment: you probably need this formula: =IF(B10="Male",495/1.0324-0.19077*log10(B13-B12)+0.15456*LOG10(B11)-450,495/1.29579-0.35004*LOG10(B13+B14-B12)+0.221*LOG10(B11)-450)

Comment: See that's the formula I used, but didn't seem to work. Now there's no error but the woman's calculation is really far out

Comment: ... for the values used, with a result of -68 when it should be 41

Comment: 41 or 31? This should give you the correct result in metric units, but it returns 31.54: =IF(B10="Male",
86.01*LOG10((B13-B12)/2.54)-70.041*LOG10(B11/2.54)+36.76,
163.205*LOG10((B13+B14-B12)/2.54)-97.684*LOG10(B11/2.54)-78.387
)

Comment: No it should definitely be 41 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either

```
=IF(B10="Male",
495/(1.0324-0.19077*log10(B13-B12)+0.15456*LOG10(B11))-450,
495/(1.29579-0.35004*LOG10(B13+B14-B12)+0.221*LOG10(B11))-450
)
```

or

```
=IF(B10="Male",
86.01*LOG10((B13-B12)/2.54)-70.041*LOG10(B11/2.54)+36.76,
163.205*LOG10((B13+B14-B12)/2.54)-97.684*LOG10(B11/2.54)-78.387
)
```

Comment: The first one worked and gave me 41. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[The formula is this site](https://www.calculator.net/body-fat-calculator.html) is different from yours, which gives a result of 41.

Comment: But they are the same as the ones I've used. Can I ask what's different?  Abdomen, navel and waist will all be the same measurement I'm using.

Comment: It is a math problem... You have to enclose the divider: `495/(1.29579 - 0.35004×log10(waist+hip-neck) + 0.22100×log10(height))-450`